# Ignoring mocked model calls in Spock

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I am testing a controller in Grails. It is using a model which has this method:

```
def beforeInsert() {
    if (password != null) {
        encodePassword()
    }
}

protected void encodePassword() {
    password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
}
```

When I try to test a method that saves the password to the database it returns this message: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method encodePassword() on null object`

How do I tell the test to just mock that method call or ignore that method call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like below in your controller test.

```
Domain.metaClass.beforeInsert = {-> }
```

PS: I have not tried this

If possible please paste you unit test code as well.

Comment: Doing that, you will disable the beforeInsert logic

Comment: @FranGarcía Yes, the person asked for ignoring the method call: 

How do I tell the test to just mock that method call or ignore that method call?

Comment: Yeah. I already solved this but forgot to post the answer. I'm not sure if your method will work but it might because what I did was a variant of your method. Instead of of overriding the `beforeInsert` method I overrode the `encodePassword` method. But it's pretty much the same so I'll just accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the springSecurityService in the controller itself.

```
def springSecurityService
controller.springSecurityService = springSecurityService
```